# Change data_root for liip imagine bundle

Tags: symfony, liipimaginebundle

I want to store and retrieve images from a different directory than what's configured in Liip's own shipped configuration.

Software used:

- Liip imagine 1.9.1
- Symfony 3.4.4
- PHP 7.1.27
- Sylius 1.1

Problem I see: adding my own configuration for data_loader > data_root results in having an array property for data_root. Liip then uses the first value in the array. As the app's custom config is loaded last, its value is last in that array, and therefore not used.

vendor\sylius\sylius\src\Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Resources\config\app\config.yml:

```
liip_imagine:
    loaders:
        default:
            filesystem:
                data_root: "%kernel.root_dir%/../web/media/image"
```

app\config\config.yml:

```
liip_imagine:
    loaders:
        default:
            filesystem:
                  data_root: "/var/www/data/image"
```

php bin/console debug:config LiipImagineBundle:

```
liip_imagine:
    loaders:
        default:
            filesystem:
                data_root:
                    - /var/www/code/symfony/app/../web/media/image
                    - /var/www/data/image
                locator: filesystem
```

I tried defining a custom dataloader, but was not able to get that to work. It seems the custom dataloader must also be defined as a service, but it's not entirely clear to me how I can wire a FileSystemLoader (especially its dependencies).